# Why not running npm test on the docker image generated by skaffold?

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-2, jenkins-x

This is the default `Jenkinsfile` generated by `jx`

```
container('nodejs') {
  sh "npm install" #line 2
  sh "CI=true DISPLAY=:99 npm test" #line 3
  sh 'export VERSION=$PREVIEW_VERSION && \
     skaffold build -f skaffold.yaml' #line 4


  sh "jx step post build --image $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$ORG/$APP_NAME:$PREVIEW_VERSION"
}
```

`skaffold build` would eventually run `docker build` and the `Dockerfile` also has `npm install` (re-running the same thing as line 2 above)

I understand that `npm install` at line 2 is to prepare for `npm test` at line 3. But I am curious why not just run the test on the generated docker file?

```
container('nodejs') {
  sh 'export VERSION=$PREVIEW_VERSION && \
     skaffold build -f skaffold.yaml'
  sh 'docker run IMAGE_GENERATED_BY_SKAFFOLD npm test'


  sh "jx step post build --image $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$ORG/$APP_NAME:$PREVIEW_VERSION"
}
```

This way, we don't need to re-execute `npm install`. Moreover, the environment where `npm test` were run is exactly similar to the one generated by `skaffold`.

I am curious, what are the considerations of Jenkins-X team for not doing that?

Answer (score 1):

yeah - I guess it  depends on the `Dockerfile` - it could do an npm install or it could just copy the built artefacts into the docker image - in this case though there’s no need to run `npm install` twice. We should fix up the build pack for npm to avoid the double `npm install`